# Why does NDK compiler not recognize a LOCAL_CFLAGS definition?

Tags: c++, makefile, android-ndk, g++, ndk-build

I have some pre-existing code I'm trying to compile into an NDK library.  There's a simply #ifndef I need to execute correctly, but in my Android.mk the var I've defined with LOCAL_CFLAGS is not recognized.  It thinks it's a command line option

When I run ndk-build with the NDK_LOG option it all compiles fine until I see this:

```
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: NDKImageProcessor <= NDKImageProcessor.cpp
arm-linux-androideabi-g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-WINONLY=1'
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/NDKImageProcessor/NDKImageProcessor.o] Error 1
```

I'm simply trying to get the following from being included in compilation:

```
#ifndef WINONLY
    #import <CoreGraphics/CGGeometry.h>
#endif
```

Android.mk is pretty straightforward:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := NDKImageProcessor

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := NDKImageProcessor.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += ../../../../SharedSrc/Image.cpp

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog

LOCAL_CFLAGS := -WINONLY=1

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

If I simply do not add that LOCAL_CFLAGS line the compiler tries to compile that iOS code, which is a no-go obviously.

Comment: You probably want `add_definitions`. In the end, that also ends up on the command line to the compiler, but it's a bit clearer semantically.

Comment: @MSalters, thanks for the help.  I tried Michael's bc it was first and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Invocation.html) (it should be the same if you use Clang):

> `-D name`
>   Predefine name as a macro, with definition 1. 
>   `-D name=definition`
>   The contents of `definition` are tokenized and processed as if they appeared during translation phase three in a ‘#define’ directive. In particular, the definition will be truncated by embedded newline characters.

So to define `WINONLY` with the value 1 you'd use:

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DWINONLY=1
```

or simply

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DWINONLY
```

Comment: that was it.  Thanks especially for the detailed answer with an example.